# Why do I get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"?

Tags: ruby, json

I have some code which I run in very similar circumstances. This is the first circumstance, where I have an `imdb_id` of a film I want details of:

```
url = "http://mymovieapi.com/?id=#{self.imdb_id}&type=json&plot=none&episode=0&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0"
doc = Hpricot(open(url)).to_s
json = JSON.parse(doc)

puts json
puts json["imdb_id"]
```

And this gives the following result:

```
{"rating_count"=>493949,
"genres"=>["Drama", "Romance"],
"rated"=>"PG-13",
"language"=>["English", "French", "German", "Swedish", "Italian", "Russian"],
"rating"=>7.6,
"country"=>["USA"],
"release_date"=>19980403,
"title"=>"Titanic",
"year"=>1997,
"filming_locations"=>"Santa Clarita, California, USA",
"imdb_id"=>"tt0120338",
"directors"=>["James Cameron"],
"writers"=>["James Cameron"],
"actors"=>["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Billy Zane", "Kathy Bates", "Frances Fisher", "Gloria Stuart", "Bill Paxton", "Bernard Hill", "David Warner", "Victor Garber", "Jonathan Hyde", "Suzy Amis", "Lewis Abernathy", "Nicholas Cascone", "Anatoly M. Sagalevitch"],
"also_known_as"=>["Tai tan ni ke hao"],
"poster"=>{"imdb"=>"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg", "cover"=>"http://imdb-poster.b0.upaiyun.com/000/120/338.jpg!cover?_upt=66ac07591382594194"},
"runtime"=>["194 min"],
"type"=>"M",
"imdb_url"=>"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/"}

tt0120338
```

This is as expected. In the second circumstance, I have the `title` and `year` of the same film:

```
url = "http://mymovieapi.com/?title=#{self.title}&type=json&plot=simple&episode=0&limit=1&year=#{self.year}&yg=1&mt=none&lang=en-US&offset=&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0"
doc = Hpricot(open(url)).to_s
json = JSON.parse(doc)

puts json
puts json["imdb_id"]
```

From this, I get the exact same JSON output:

```
{"rating_count"=>493949,
"genres"=>["Drama", "Romance"],
"rated"=>"PG-13", "language"=>["English", "French", "German", "Swedish", "Italian", "Russian"],
"rating"=>7.6,
"country"=>["USA"],
"release_date"=>19980403,
"title"=>"Titanic",
"year"=>1997,
"filming_locations"=>"Santa Clarita, California, USA",
"imdb_id"=>"tt0120338",
"directors"=>["James Cameron"],
"writers"=>["James Cameron"],
"actors"=>["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Billy Zane", "Kathy Bates", "Frances Fisher", "Gloria Stuart", "Bill Paxton", "Bernard Hill", "David Warner", "Victor Garber", "Jonathan Hyde", "Suzy Amis", "Lewis Abernathy", "Nicholas Cascone", "Anatoly M. Sagalevitch"],
"also_known_as"=>["Tai tan ni ke hao"],
"poster"=>{"imdb"=>"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg",
"cover"=>"http://imdb-poster.b0.upaiyun.com/000/120/338.jpg!cover?_upt=ec8bdec31382594417"},
"runtime"=>["194 min"],
"type"=>"M",
"imdb_url"=>"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/"}
```

But when I try and call `puts json["imdb_id"]`, I get this error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

This always happens when fetching using the `title` and `year`, yet it seems unexplained as the JSON output is exactly the same.

Comment: Is it "put json["imdb_id"]" or "puts"? And can you post the json returned for the second type?

Comment: @AmithKoujalgi It's puts, I typed that small part out here and made a mistake. I've copied in the 2nd json output, but it is exactly the same.

Comment: Why are you using Hpricot? And why are you using Hpricot to "parse" the JSON output received? First, it's not needed, it's also been replaced by Nokogiri, so, *IF* you needed to parse HTML, which you don't, you'd do better with a newer HTML parser.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm fairly new to JSON (this is my first real app with it), so thanks for the heads up on that. I wasn't sure how to get the JSON from the webpage, and I was using Hpricot elsewhere so used it to do that. How should I be doing it? Using Nokogiri, or some other way?

Comment: Don't use Nokogiri or Hpricot. You're requesting a JSON response and that's what you're getting.

Comment: @theTinMan So what would I pass as an argument into JSON.parse()? It has to be a string of JSON, so how would i get that from the webpage?

Comment: See my answer. You're not looking at the data you're getting back. And, it's obvious that the answer you selected *didn't* solve your question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the exception, it seems that `json` in the second response is an array with only one element, so the output of `puts json` is the same (brackets don't get output with `puts`), but `json["string"]` fails because `[]` expects an `Integer` to use as index.

Check `p json` or that `json.is_a?(Array)` and if it is indeed an array, try with `json.first['imdb_id']`.

Comment: I dont see this as an array.

Comment: `puts [1]` will output the same as `puts 1`(`1`) because it will output each element separated by a new line. From the output given in the question is impossible to know if json is the hash shown or actually an array containing the hash shown. Andrew should check `json.class` or `json.inspect`

Comment: The second JSON response IS returning an array. Here's the first one: `doc[0..5] # => "{\"rati"` and the second one: `doc[0..5] # => "[{\"rat"`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what's wrong and how to fix it:

- You're NOT getting HTML back, so you do *NOT* need to parse HTML. Look at the contents of `doc` in the examples below. Notice, there is no HTML parsing going on, nor is there any need for it because you're specifically requesting a JSON response: `type=json`.
- The first request returns a single response because you're asking for a specific `imdb_id`. You can only get one response back, so you get just a single object/hash.
- The second request returns an array of responses, because there *could* be multiple items with the same `title` and `year`, though it seems unlikely. As a result, you have to grab a particular item from the returned array after parsing the JSON. I used `first`, but your mileage might vary since you could get multiple items; You'll have to figure out which is the appropriate one if you do get more than one.

Here's some code:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

imdb_id = 'tt0120338'
url = "http://mymovieapi.com/?id=#{ imdb_id }&type=json&plot=none&episode=0&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0"
doc = open(url).read
doc[0..5] # => "{\"rati"
json = JSON.parse(doc) # => {"rating_count"=>493949, "genres"=>["Drama", "Romance"], "rated"=>"PG-13", "language"=>["English", "French", "German", "Swedish", "Italian", "Russian"], "rating"=>7.6, "country"=>["USA"], "release_date"=>19980403, "title"=>"Titanic", "year"=>1997, "filming_locations"=>"Santa Clarita, California, USA", "imdb_id"=>"tt0120338", "directors"=>["James Cameron"], "writers"=>["James Cameron"], "actors"=>["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Billy Zane", "Kathy Bates", "Frances Fisher", "Gloria Stuart", "Bill Paxton", "Bernard Hill", "David Warner", "Victor Garber", "Jonathan Hyde", "Suzy Amis", "Lewis Abernathy", "Nicholas Cascone", "Anatoly M. Sagalevitch"], "also_known_as"=>["Tai tan ni ke hao"], "poster"=>{"imdb"=>"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg", "cover"=>"http://imdb-poster.b0.upaiyun.com/000/120/338.jpg!cover?_upt=7dedce781382606097"}, "runtime"=>["194 min"], "type"=>"M", "imdb_url"=>"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/"}
json["imdb_id"] # => "tt0120338"
```

This returned a single item as a JSON response. You can see that by looking at the `doc` variable and see that it is JSON, *NOT* HTML. Parsing it using the JSON parser returned a hash.

```
url = "http://mymovieapi.com/?title=#{ json['title'] }&type=json&plot=simple&episode=0&limit=1&year=#{ json['year'] }&yg=1&mt=none&lang=en-US&offset=&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0"
doc = open(url).read
doc[0..5] # => "[{\"rat"
json = JSON.parse(doc).first # => {"rating_count"=>493949, "genres"=>["Drama", "Romance"], "rated"=>"PG-13", "language"=>["English", "French", "German", "Swedish", "Italian", "Russian"], "rating"=>7.6, "country"=>["USA"], "release_date"=>19980403, "title"=>"Titanic", "year"=>1997, "filming_locations"=>"Santa Clarita, California, USA", "imdb_id"=>"tt0120338", "directors"=>["James Cameron"], "writers"=>["James Cameron"], "actors"=>["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Billy Zane", "Kathy Bates", "Frances Fisher", "Gloria Stuart", "Bill Paxton", "Bernard Hill", "David Warner", "Victor Garber", "Jonathan Hyde", "Suzy Amis", "Lewis Abernathy", "Nicholas Cascone", "Anatoly M. Sagalevitch"], "plot_simple"=>"A seventeen-year-old aristocrat, expecting to be married to a rich claimant by her mother, falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.", "poster"=>{"imdb"=>"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg", "cover"=>"http://imdb-poster.b0.upaiyun.com/000/120/338.jpg!cover?_upt=7dedce781382606097"}, "runtime"=>["194 min"], "type"=>"M", "imdb_url"=>"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/", "also_known_as"=>["Tai tan ni ke hao"]}
json["imdb_id"] # => "tt0120338"
```

This request returned an array of hashes, which is reasonable. The JSON string is an array, which is visible in the `doc` variable. Parsing it, then grabbing just the first element makes it possible to read the value of `imdb_id`.

Again, notice that there is no HTML parser involved, nor is one needed. You have to look at the data you're getting back, don't just assume.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be somewhere else in your code from what I can tell.

I set the JSON you gave as your output to the variable `a` in IRB: (JSON from your second example)

```
1.9.3p194 :043 > a
 => {"rating_count"=>493949, "genres"=>["Drama", "Romance"], "rated"=>"PG-13", "language"=>["English", "French", "German", "Swedish", "Italian", "Russian"], "rating"=>7.6, "country"=>["USA"], "release_date"=>19980403, "title"=>"Titanic", "year"=>1997, "filming_locations"=>"Santa Clarita, California, USA", "imdb_id"=>"tt0120338", "directors"=>["James Cameron"], "writers"=>["James Cameron"], "actors"=>["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Billy Zane", "Kathy Bates", "Frances Fisher", "Gloria Stuart", "Bill Paxton", "Bernard Hill", "David Warner", "Victor Garber", "Jonathan Hyde", "Suzy Amis", "Lewis Abernathy", "Nicholas Cascone", "Anatoly M. Sagalevitch"], "also_known_as"=>["Tai tan ni ke hao"], "poster"=>{"imdb"=>"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg", "cover"=>"http://imdb-poster.b0.upaiyun.com/000/120/338.jpg!cover?_upt=ec8bdec31382594417"}, "runtime"=>["194 min"], "type"=>"M", "imdb_url"=>"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/"}
```

Then I called:

```
1.9.3p194 :046 > puts a["imdb_id"]
tt0120338
 => nil
```

This gave me the right output.